# Please validate my idea to promote the site.

Tags: discussion, publicity

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38772/gerrymandering-optimization).

After seeing [Mr Weiner's tweet](https://twitter.com/#!/ZachWeiner/statuses/68779708438953984) about the question on reddit, [I asked him](https://twitter.com/#!/juanformoso/statuses/68780888665763840) to try asking it here to compare quality and response times.

Then I remember Jeff saying in a podcast or a blog post that a valid practice would be to ask on behalf of the person, and then present them with the answer, and that this is a great way to promote the network.

So that's what I did.

Let me know if it's not appropriate for this community.

Comment: My personal opinion:
It is an interesting question, but there are two problems in the current formulation:

1. I don't think that it is reasonable to assume that all mathematicians know what Gerrymandering is, so a short explanation would have been appropriate.

2. It is not clear how the perimeter of an electoral district should be defined, so that should be part of the question.

Comment: Interesting, I actually didn't know:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering